# MapFragment and surfaceView play video, respectively, on the two fragments, add to the same Activity to switch

Tags: android, mapfragment

`Com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment` is placed in a fragment, and the surfaceView plays the video in another fragment.

The two fragments are in the same Activity and click on the lower right corner to switch.

When the map is full screen, click the lower right corner to display the video. Click the lower right corner again, the video full screen display, the lower right corner of the map, but this time the map was covered.

It is my first time with Google Maps for development, hope to get help.